# @NLConstraint with vectorized constraint JuMP/Julia

Tags: optimization, julia-jump

I am trying to solve a problem involving the equating of sums of exponentials.

This is how I would do it hardcoded:

```
@NLconstraint(m, exp(x[25])==exp(x[14])+exp(x[18]))
```

This works fine with the rest of the code. However, when I try to do it for an arbitrary set of equations like the above I get an error. Here's my code:

```
@NLconstraint(m,[k=1:length(LHSSum)],sum(exp.(LHSSum[k][i]) for i=1:length(LHSSum[k]))==sum(exp.(RHSSum[k][i]) for i=1:length(RHSSum[k])))
```

where `LHSSum` and `RHSSum` are arrays containing arrays of the elements that need to be exponentiated and then summed over. That is `LHSSum[1]=[x[1],x[2],x[3],...,x[n]]`. Where `x[i]` are variables of type `JuMP.Variable`. Note that `length(LHSSum)=length(RHSSum)`.

The error returned is:

```
LoadError: exp is not defined for type Variable. Are you trying to build a nonlinear problem? Make sure you use @NLconstraint/@NLobjective.
```

So a simple solution would be to simply do all the exponentiating and summing outside of the `@NLconstraint` function, so the input would be a scalar. However, this too presents a problem since `exp(x)` is not defined since x is of type `JuMP.variable`, whereas exp expects something of type real. This is strange since I am able to calculate exponentials just fine when the function is called within an `@NLconstraint()`. I.e. when I code this line`@NLconstraint(m,exp(x)==exp(z)+exp(y))` instead of the earlier line, no errors are thrown.

Another thing I thought to do would be a Taylor Series expansion, but this too presents a problem since it goes into `@NLconstraint` land for powers greater than 2, and then I get stuck with the same vectorization problem.

So I feel stuck, I feel like if JuMP would allow for the vectorized evaluation of `@NLconstraint` like it does for `@constraint`, this would not even be an issue. Another fix would be if JuMP implements it's own exp function to allow for the exponentiation of `JuMP.Variable` type. However, as it is I don't see a way to solve this problem in general using the JuMP framework. Do any of you have any solutions to this problem? Any clever workarounds that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why `i` isn't used in the expressions you wrote. Do you mean:

```
@NLconstraint(m, [k = 1:length(LHSSum)],
              sum(exp(LHSSum[k][i]) for i in 1:length(LHSSum[k]))
              ==
              sum(exp(RHSSum[k][i]) for i in 1:length(RHSSum[k])))
```

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I fixed that, however, I still get the error: ERROR: LoadError: exp is not defined for type Variable. Are you trying to build a nonlinear problem? Make sure you use @NLconstraint/@NLobjective...

Comment: Here's the updated code:`@NLconstraint(m,[k=1:length(LHSSum)],sum(exp.(LHSSum[k][i]) for i=1:length(LHSSum[k]))==sum(exp.(RHSSum[k][i]) for i=1:length(RHSSum[k])))`

Comment: If I understand correctly, `LHSSum[k][i]` is a scalar JuMP variable. You should be able to write `exp(LHSSum[k][i])` instead of `exp.(LHSSum[k][i])`.